Calculating the $Q$ value for $^6\text{Li}+p\to\,{}^3\text{He}+{}^4\text{He}$
This is question 9a from Chapter 11 in Krane. I've tried to just fill in all the atomic masses in the formula like this
$$Q = (6.015121 \ \text{u} +1.007276 \ \text{u} - 3.016029 \ \text{u} - 4.002603 \ \text{u})\ c^2,$$
but then I get $3.507 \ \text{MeV}$ and it needs to be $4.020 \ \text{MeV}$.
I'm completely new to nuclear physics and I have no idea what I'm doing wrong here...

A common source of errors in this kind of calculation involves the electron masses.

Im prety sure took the right atomic masses but then again its weird that its wrong then

It's pretty suspicious that the discrepancy is 0.513 MeV, which is very close to the electron mass.

Yes very good point, I feel like i have that discrepancy all the time but I do not see where it comes from

Using the 2020 Atomic Mass Evaluation numbers and using $c^{2} = 931.494103$ MeV/amu I get 4.0194 MeV. Your error is you used the mass for the proton, not for hydrogen atom. H atom = 1.007825 amu

they do ask the reaction with a proton in the book not with H, i made a mistake typing this over and fixed it

Look at your equation. You have 3 electrons on the left and 4 electrons on the right. It is thus unbalanced. Either you include a spectator electron on the left, or you remove an electron on the right. Or you remove all electrons, in which case you have to do a lot more computations for very little gain.

So even if the reaction just adds a proton one might still need to add an electron as well? I understand that we need the balance i just find it weird that Krane asks the question in that way

I am not sure about where you got the molar masses from (in my edition of Krane they are not given in the question) but with the values I found online, this is what I get:
\begin{aligned}
Q &= (6.015122 \ \text{u} +1.00784 \ \text{u} - 3.016029 \ \text{u}  - 4.002603 \ \text{u}) \ c^2 \\
&= 4.33 \times 10^{-3} \ c^2 \times 931.5 \ \text{MeV}/c^2,
\end{aligned}
where $u = 931.5 \ \text{MeV}/c^2$.
The final result is $Q = 4.03 \ \text{MeV}$, which is closer to the value you're getting.
Hope this helped.

I've usually found that calculations are usually within ~100 keV of the written value because of different molar masses cited in different places, so $4.03\pm0.01$ is right on target.

How where dit you find the mass for a proton like that? This one is for a H atom but the question states a proton, I do feel like the mistake has something to do with this as there is an electron just on the loose in the reaction now

@RoITF73 All of your other masses are for neutral atoms, so a bare proton on the left side gives you an electron imbalance. Read your mass tables carefully.

Aaahh yes i found my electron, if i understand correctly you have to always look if there might be an electron on the loose somewhere when you are working with just a bare proton in the reaction, and if this is the case one should add this mass as well?

This sort of problem is why I recommend using "mass excess" instead of using the total mass.  The mass excess is the difference between the total mass of a neutral atom and its atomic number in daltons.  (One dalton is also known as one atomic mass unit, abbreviated a.m.u. or just u.)  The National Nuclear Data Center tabulates mass excesses in energy units, saving you a conversion.  If you do this sort of thing a lot, their "Nuclear Wallet Cards" are available in a free-for-you handy little book that fits in your pocket.
For your problem we have



nuclide
mass excess




$\rm^1H$
7.29 MeV


$\rm^3He$
14.93 MeV


$\rm^4He$
2.42 MeV


$\rm^6Li$
14.09 MeV



The difference between the initial mass excess 21.38 MeV and the final mass excess 17.35 MeV is in fact 4.03 MeV, as Krane gives.  (An interesting assignment is to decide whether you trust his fourth significant figure.)
It appears you have in fact used the bare proton mass $1.007\,276\rm\,u$ on the left side, but the masses of neutral helium atoms on the right side.  You are off by one electron mass, as predicted by your first commenter.  Read your data sources carefully.
In a real experiment you would probably put a proton beam on a solid lithium target, and you'd expect the helium fragments to be ionized.  These changes would introduce sub-keV-ish changes to the actual Q-value associated with the electron binding energies --- another reason to mistrust a result given to four significant figures.

MeV to 4 sf is still at keV goodness. The results will be good to quite a few more digits. Instead, it is that you have neglected input energies that is the way bigger issue.

Both good points. I got further into the weeds than I intended while writing this on my lunch break, so my coverage was uneven.
